# NSTableView only display button when cell is selected

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview

I have an NSTableview in view based mode, in it I have custom NSTableViewCells.  Each cell has a button, but I only want the button to be displayed if the cell is selected.  So when the cell becomes deselected I want to hide the button.  I have tried to iterate through each row unsuccessfully and am unsure as to how to go about this.

This is what I'm doing to show the button

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    ...

    //Hide / show dropdown menus
    NSInteger selected = [_tableView selectedRow];
    CustomCell *cell = [_tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:selected makeIfNecessary:NO];
    [cell setIsMenuHidden:NO];

}
```

Comment: reload table after doing your code... might work...

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working, it wasn't working before as I was setting the button as hidden in the -viewForTableColumn:Row method!  Would still like to know if there is a better way to do this :)

```
//Hide / show dropdown menus
NSInteger selected = [_tableView selectedRow];
for(int i = 0; i < [_tableView numberOfRows]; i++) {
    if(i == selected) {
        [[_tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:i makeIfNecessary:NO] setIsMenuHidden:NO];
    } else {
        [[_tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:i makeIfNecessary:NO] setIsMenuHidden:YES];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom cell view, you can override `-viewWillDraw`. Call through to `super` and then make whatever adjustments based on the state that you want.

You can use the table view's `-rowForView:` and `-isRowSelected:` methods to determine whether to hide or show the button. Alternatively, the cell view's superview will be the row view and `NSTableRowView` has a `selected` property (`-isSelected` getter).