# Hide a button in a non selected cellView with bindings

Tags: button, nstableview, hidden, key-bindings

I begin developing with Cocoa. I have an ArrayController which provides datas to a NSTableView with DataBindings.
I added a button on my cellView and want it visible only when the cell (or row, there’s only one column) is selected.
I added a Boolean property to my dataModel « estSelectionne » to activate or not the « Hidden » of my button.
My question:

- how to set the value of the « estSelectionne » Boolean? (Tried to addObserver…)
- or better, can I set directly the Boolean Hidden in IB, and how?
  Thank you in advance

Comment: See [NSTableView only display button when cell is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854366/nstableview-only-display-button-when-cell-is-selected)

Comment: Is the data model used exclusively by the table view?

Comment: Thank you, the reference isn't kvo friendly...

Comment: My dataModel is used in another tableView and with drag/drop

Comment: Setting the value of a boolean is usually something like `someObject.estSelectionne = true`. The Hidden Check box in IB is at the bottom of the Attributes Inspector panel (but it is ignored if the Hidden binding is used). If this is not what you're asking then edit the question please.

Answer (score 0):

I set the value of my model property "*estSelectionne*" in an override of NSTableView.isRowSelected and it's **OK**